# Add dependencies to Aurelia project

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

I set up an Aurelia project using the minimal project given [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1).

Then I added the `fetch-client` using `npm install aurelia-fetch-client --save` command. It updated `package.json` to contain following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

But when I added `import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';` to my `app.js` file and tried running the app, but got following error:

```
system.js:4 GET http://localhost:5000/aurelia-fetch-client 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I add that? Where does this project keep track of its dependencies? I have seen lots of tutorials which help setting up the fetch client in `aurelia cli` projects. How about the project given [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1)?

Comment: Maybe you have to do `import {HttpClient} from './node_modules/aurelia-fetch-client'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the problem is my `node_modules` is outside `wwwroot`, and `aspnet` is serving `wwwrooot` folder so it can't access `node_modules`.

Comment: This article is not a production-ready set up. It is just a simple example of how the framework works. If you want to install modules and/or send your app to production, you should use `aurelia-cli` or one of the skeleton projects https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/latest instead

Comment: Thanks, I can stick to `cli`; btw is there any way for me to make it production-ready just so I can add a few dependencies?

Comment: In the end, what did you decide?  Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Well, I was not able to add it to the minimal project above; I ended up using the skeleton Typescript project.

Answer (score 2):

First, follow Fabio Luz's advice above and actually install either `aurelia-cli` or a skeleton framework.

Then, I have found this next step to be one of the most common sources of confusion for most people who are learning Aurelia.  After installing new modules via `npm`, you have to manually list them as a dependency in `aurelia.json` (in your `aurelia_project` folder).  For example, you would list `aurelia-fetch-client` as follows:

```
"dependencies": [
  "aurelia-binding",
  "aurelia-bootstrapper",
  "aurelia-dependency-injection",
  "aurelia-event-aggregator",
  ...
  "aurelia-fetch-client",
  ...
```

After it is listed as a dependency, it will be included in the `vendor.js` bundle (in the CLI, by running `au run --watch`) so that it can be accessed by your application when you import it in individual components.

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
```

Comment: Just to note, there is work currently happening to automate the process of modifying the `aurelia.json` file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of and grateful for that work! If you're a part of it, thank you!

Comment: I wish I could say I was, but I'm just the bearer of good news this time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I faced the same confusion when I used `cli` before, in this project I couldn't find `aurelia.json` or similar config file. Is there any way for me to add that?

Comment: You can't just add `aurelia.json` (even if you did, it would be ignored). You need to start with `npm install aurelia-cli --save` and it will be created.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this (using the project generated by the CLI):

```
npm i whatwg-fetch --save
npm i aurelia-fetch-client --save
```

add "aurelia-fetch-client" to dependencies in aurelia_project/aurelia.json

example of app.js:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let client = new HttpClient();

export class App{
  activate(){
    client.fetch('http://...json');
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{

    console.log(data)

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also install dependencies with the CLI itself.

It doesn't always get it 100% correct but can point you in the right direction if struggling.

For example `au install aurelia-fetch-client`

It will download the dependency, add to `packages.json` and attempt to create an entry for the bundling.